# Calculate circle packing

Tags: haskell, math

I need to mathematically calculate the **position `[x, y]`** and the **radius** where `C ∈ N` and **C** is a circle that can be positioned inside another circle with scalable radius and being traversed until reaching a leaf.

[image]

Being `x` the horizontal scale, `y` the vertical scale and `r` the radius, I need to infinetely position subcircles inside it, in a perfect geometric form. I've made some math proofs to calculate the density, but I'm not having good results: https://gist.github.com/haskellcamargo/89384ac17ba0131115c7

I define `Circle` as:

```
data Shape = Circle Double Double Double deriving (Show)
```

But I cannot find a **deterministic** way to prove the `x` and `y` position when a circle is inserted inside, with a perfect geometric form.

[image]

I found ways to calculate the density of a subcircle, but with special calcs according to the amount of subcircles, but the `x` and `y` are variant, with the unique warranty that the composed form where `n > 3` will be composed by triangles. I know that I must work on angle, but I'm stuck on this in the last 2 weeks.

The question is: Can I use deterministic calculations to have the position `x`, `y` and the `radius` giving `n`, being `n` the number of elements? The final result would be like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535, but with the absolute position, as calculated by D3.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. Are you looking for a way how to compute positions of circles for [optimal packing of _n_ circles of the same radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)?

Comment: Yes, I already can calculate the density, but I'm having troubles with gettint the absolute position for each sub-circle.

Comment: At least in your example, there is no deterministic position for the two inner circles, you can set the center of one of the the inner circles on a circle to concentric to the center of the larger circle with half radius.  You have one degree of freedom without any other constraints.